Markdown / Marked 2 Image Resizing
I am writing a lot of Markdown files for documentation and preview the results in "Marked 2" on MacOS. I embed a lot of screenshot images and every time I am asking myself why is there no proper image resizing functionality built in the Markdown implementation. I might have small images which I don't want to be expanded over the whole page width.
Previously there was small functionality in Marked 2 where you could add e.g. =100x in the Markdown image markup and the image was then resized to 100px. But of course it only worked for the preview with Marked 2 and GitHub couldn't display it.
E.g.
![](./pic/pic1_50.png =100x20)

To skip height:
![](./pic/pic1s.png =250x)

To skip width:
![](./pic/pic1s.png =x250)

However, the Marked 2 solution also doesn't work anymore. My old markdown files where I used this pattern are not showing the images anymore, but instead just the image markup String.
Does anyone know why? Is it a setting in Marked 2? And why can't there be a out-of-the-box Markdown solution for this?
I think a lot of Markdown users are using images in their .md files.

This question is similar to: Changing image size in Markdown. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

=100x20 isn't a part of neither Markdown standard nor any popular Markdown dialect. Most of markdown editors support HTML element as a dialect feature, so you can try the <image> tag with inline CSS:
<img src="PICTURE.png" alt="PICTURE_NAME" style="zoom:50%;" />


Yes, I know... but why? Why to use html markup and not a easy to use Markdown markup function? In my Markdown files which I sometimes read without a preview I don't want to see HTML code.

The pure Markdown standard hasn't been maintained since its last release since 2004 according to Wikipedia. Even the latest version (0.31.2) of CommonMark doesn't set specific rules for image-resizing, but the documentation says it supports HTML tag natively. So currently there's no way to resize images except for the "ugly" HTML, just accept it as a feature. :)

It sounds like you're looking for an easy way to resize images.
You can use custom CSS to resize all images so that they are not so large.
For instance, let's say you want to vary the scale of your images. Go into the CSS file that governs your images and define:
img { 
  display: block; 
  float: none; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  scale: 100%; 
} 

The scale percentage is what defines the size of your images.

It would be good to know how you can use CSS in a Markdown document... (But luckily that has already been answered: How to use CSS in Markdown?)
